# Access Confirmation message

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database that is saved in a network location so that any of the 600 employees who work at the company can access the database. When they open the main form it runs a make-table query. However there is a popup from MS Access stating "You are about to run a make-table query that will modify data in your table. Do you want to continue?"

The form will not run correctly if they do not press yes so I want to suppress this prompt so that it does not ask them. I changed the settings from the Options>Edit/Find>Confirm menu so that it doesn't show this confirmation. However, this is apparently a local setting so to enforce this every user would have to change those settings.

Is there any other possible solution to suppress the confirmation message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, from VBA:

```
DoCmd.ShowWarnings False            ' Don't show warning popup
DoCmd.RunQuery "MyMakeTableQuery"   ' Run the make table query silently
DoCmd.ShowWarnings True             ' Turn warnings back on
```

Comment: I found it to be DoCmd.SetWarnings not DoCmd.ShowWarnings

Answer (score 3):

There is so much wrong here, I hardly know where to start:

1. you can't possible have an Access database used by 600 people.
2. if more than one person opens it and runs the MakeTable, it will break, because you'd be making a structural change that collides between the two users.
3. turning off error notification is a HUGE MISTAKE. You don't know exactly which errors you might end up ignoring.
4. turning off SetWarnings means that you can get inconsistent updates from a SQL DML statement, and then you have no way to know which data was updated or not.
5. MakeTable queries do not belong in any production application. Instead, create a persistent table, and clean it out and append new records to it. But it doesn't belong in your main application -- this is the very definition of temporary data, since it's constantly being replaced, so it needs to be in a separate temp database.
6. you'd likely want all users to have their own temp databases so there are no collisions if more than one opens the app at a time.

Comment: Well said. And I would add that an action query just by opening a form makes me highly suspicious about the design of that app !

Comment: One slight quibble with point 1: you can't possible have an Access database used by 600 people *at once*. It's quite possible to have 600 users total if you can ensure that only a small fraction are logged in at any given time (due to shift work, for example). No argument with the rest.

Comment: If 600 people are theoretically allowed to use the database, I'd be VERY WORRIED. My guess is that the number is vastly overstated, regardless of whether it is intended to represent the non-simultaneous user population or not.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` to stop the message box from popping up. Be warned, however, that this action is global to the Access application. You have to re-enable warnings with `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
Application.SetOption "Confirm Action Queries", False
```

If you don't already, you may want to have a hidden form open every time the database is opened. You can use the OnOpen event of that form to run startup code like the above.